# cshell setenv: Too many arguments

Tags: csh

i have in c-shell

```
    set value_str ="one three"
    set line_seprator = ","
    set value_and_sperator = "$value_str$line_seprator"
    setenv STRING_CONCAT $STRING_CONCAT$value_and_sperator
```

and im getting error:

```
setenv: Too many arguments.
```

this is way i what to set global variable  in the script , any idea why im getting the error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just need to enclose the string in quotes - `csh` is confused by the separator otherwise.

```
setenv STRING_CONCAT "$STRING_CONCAT$value_and_sperator"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set a list separated by spaces.

```
setenv value_str "val1 val2"
```

and then in  the script

```
set varxyz= ( ${value_str} )
set xyzList = "$varxyz"

foreach val ( $xyzList )
 echo "val: $val"
end
```

Answer (score -1):

I feel that most `setenv` problems arise because people do not understand that the env variables are scalar ones, i.e. while you may loop on the values of `$a` defined by

```
set a = (1 2 3)
```

this is not possible with an env variable. After

```
setenv A "1 2"
```

the command

```
echo $A[1]
```

does not output the expected first component of `$A`, i.e. 1, but writes

```
1 2[1]
```

To pass a vector to a script by the env variable `A` and loop on its elements, it is possible to use

```
set a = ($A)
foreach i ($a) ...
```

Answer (score -2):

just check whether in the line where you gave setenv, line should end with $STRING_CONCAT$value_and_sperator. no tab or space afterwards. this could also give this issue. even multiple values (for eg a "." )